# QlikSense: Using variables for many columns

Tags: qliksense

I believe I've gotten the format I need that's going to best suit my end user's needs, but one last detail I'd like to have incorporated is a drop-down variable to choose how data is viewed. I have staged my data to spit out all values in mCg (micrograms) but I'd like to use a variable and drop-down option to give the ability to see/select values in mg (milligram) view. Here's what I've done so far:

I've added a variable:

[image]

I've attempted a simple test of the functionality:

[image]

While even this is not even affecting one column, I have 24 columns that will need to be affected:

[image]

So to be clear, all of these numerical values are in mCg, but when I choose mg I'd like them all to display in mg which is simply mCg / 1000. Where am I going wrong?

---

**EDIT 1:**

I've since tried something else, but without any luck still. I tested a single column again with the following:

[image]

Comment: I have since discovered a way of accomplishing what I need. I believe what I was trying to do worked, technically speaking, but Qlik was unable to refresh in real time to reveal changes. I instead opted to use a similar expression in the Show Column If section and manipulate the values of two otherwise identical columns, each with a mg and a mCg value.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you'd need to do is make the variable dropdown object have two options: `mCg` with a value of `1` and then `mg` with a  value of `1000`.

Then in each column, you would simply do `=Sum([YourMeasure]) * $(Var)`.

Comment: Or maybe `/` instead of `*`, whatever the math is